# Can't debug dynamically loaded silverlight applications (xap file)

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, debugging, silverlight-4.0

I have a solution which contains multiple applications. In the 'root' application I read a config file, download the xap files and load them using some class *System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting.DeploymentCatalog* .

The problem is that I can't debug these dynamically loaded applications (the web project, I can debug the Silverlight client). Visual Studio says the breakpoint will not be hit, displaying the exclamation mark inside the yellow triangle. If I copy the dll+pdb files to root application's output folder than the breakopints become colored in full red but they still aren't being hit.

Any solutions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question:

I was able to debug my web project in Visual Studio 2010 by following the steps:

1. Web project -> Properties -> Web section -> Select *Don't open a page. Wait for a ....*
2. Start 'root' application in normal mode.
3. Right-click on web project -> Debug -> *Start new instance*.

That was it!

Answer (score 0):

Go to Properties inside the Website project, click on **Web** tab at the left side, you will find Debuggers section at the bottom. Try checking ASP.NET radio button and uncheck Silverlight radio button and see whether you are able to debug the Web project or not.

Comment: Tried it, nothing changed. I tried what you said for both main application and dynamically loaded application.

Answer (score 0):

If still this doesn't help, try unchecking **Disable script debugging** option in IE > Tools > Internet Options > Advanced